# Why does unique constraint allow only one null value?

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

I know we can add multiple NULL values but why does SQL allow only one null?

Comment: If with "SQL" you mean the SQL standard: it does allow multiple NULL values for a unique constraint

Answer (score 2):

This assumption is just not true. With a unique constraint, and nothing else, you can have as many `null`s as you want.

See, e.g., [This SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f71de/1/0).

Comment: Correct, this is how "SQL" (as in "SQL the standard") defines this requirement

Comment: Incorrect.  Different databases handle `NULL` values in unique constraints differently.

Answer (score 1):

Null - is als ao value, so for unique constraint it should be one too. But this is supported not in all DBs. MS SQL Server supports this, MySQL supports multiple nulls.

Comment: I'm surprised SQLServer does this as null literally means "value not yet set" in SQL.